# php-cgi.exe is opening up an enormous amount of instances

Tags: php, iis, service, web-deployment

I am hosting php 5.2 on IIS 8. Yes, I know that's a horrible idea, but that is reality.

The server runs out of resources after our website is up for a few hours because for some reason php-cgi.exe opens up dozens of times:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? perhaps something wrong with the php.ini file?

Could this be caused by mssql_result not closing the connection?

I followed this nifty tutorial without luck http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/fastcgi/application

I have actually been able to limit the number of instances, but then all additional requests are getting processed very slowly.

Comment: Check your IIS settings. The number of children launched is not controlled by php.

Comment: off topic, but why are you still hosting php 5.2? 5.2 was declared end-of-life more than two years ago. in fact, even 5.3 will be end-of-life fairly soon. if you're still on 5.2 you're being left behind. There's very little compatibility issues between the two (if you ignore the deprecation warnings), so not much reason not to upgrade.

Comment: @datasage you are definitely right. i was able to change the MAX INSTANCES variable in the fastcgi properties; however, now the problem is that after there are more instances, they are super super slow

Comment: @datasage any input on your end?

Comment: @Spudley i've updated slightly, would be very grateful for more of your guidance

Comment: I honestly don't know why your php programs are not terminating. I guess you could try setting the PHP timeout to a shorter duration, and get rid of them that way, but it's not an ideal solution.

Comment: thank you i really appreciate that advice. i think they do terminate eventually but not before the server runs out of resources. i see that this problem has many causes but i dont really understand how it applies to me, namely this was interesting: http://konrness.com/php5/how-to-prevent-blocking-php-requests/  do you think that this might be the issue, @Spudley?

Comment: there are many, many reasons why a program may take longer than expected to terminate. It's impossible to tell without seeing the code and spending time to debug it. I suggest you do a few tests. Maybe start with a simple 'hello world' program on the same server; see if that gets stuck. Is it the same page every time that does this? Maybe there's something specific in that page? You could try running it through a debugger or profiler like xdebug to get more info about what its doing?

Comment: @Spudley, thank you! this gives me a starting point! it looks like it doesnt really matter what page i open. even hello world gives me the same responding behavior

Comment: also im sorry to ask you again, but do yhou think that link i posted in the last comment is worth looking at?

Comment: @Spudley i would be most grateful for your continued suggestions

Comment: The link you posted is discussing an issue with php sessions on long-running php programs that blocks any other php program from using the same session. I don't think this is your problem (although your users may be experiencing it as a side-effect). I don't really have any other suggestions for you, but if a simple hello world program is doing the same thing then I would suggest you maybe have a problem with the php installation. You could try re-installing. You could also try asking for further help at http://serverfault.com/ (a sister site to SO, but focusing on issues with server software)

Comment: @Spudley thank you that was very helpful. perhaps my php.ini file is screwed up? pastebin.com/Gt4ZMSW0